# error when insert values in fields

Tags: mysql

I created a table Place in mysql. In this table there are three fields.

```
1. Place_Name varchar(20)
2. latitude  decimal(15,12)
3. longitude decimal(15,12)
```

There is a problem occurred when user inserted value like as 55636.1232 in latitude or in longitude.

Because this value is above the range of capacity of these fields. Because i allowed 3

digit before decimal point while user is trying to enter more than 3 digit before decimal

points. In this case 999.999999999999 value is inserted but i want to insert my default

value if user do such type of mistake.

I want that when user do this type of mistake then my default value should be entered in that record.

Please help me what should i do to solve such type of problem. I am waiting for your suggestions.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You can check this value before inserting, in the application.

Comment: sir if i want to make entries direct in database ? then any solution ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should set SQL Mode to [strict_all_tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-sql-mode.html) by executing

```
SET sql_mode='STRICT_ALL_TABLES';
```

This will prevent from entering invalid data and on violation will throw this MySQL error:

> Out of range value for column 'latitude' at row 1

Answer (score 0):

You can write a case statement into your mysql statement.

```
CASE case_value
    WHEN when_value THEN statement_list
    [WHEN when_value THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END CASE
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/case-statement.html

So in your case, you might write something like:

```
Insert Into coordinates (Place_Name,latitude,longitude) 
Values 
('$name',
Case $latitude When $latitude > 99.999 Then '$defaultLat' Else '$latitude' End Case, 
Case $longitude When $longitude > 99.999 Then '$defaultLong' Else '$longitude' End Case);
```